How to adapt my leaderstats script so that when a part (pointPart1) is touched, player gains points rather than point per sec like it currently is
https://pastebin.com/vPgjPdnK
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local pointPart1 = game.Workspace.PointsPlaceFolder.PointPart1

local function onCharacterAdded(character, player)
    player:SetAttribute("IsAlive", true)
    
    local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    
    humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
        local points = player.leaderstats.Points
        points.Value = 0
        player:SetAttribute("IsAlive", false)
    end)
end

local function onPlayerAdded(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local points = Instance.new("IntValue")
    points.Name = "Points"
    points.Value = 0
    points.Parent = leaderstats
    
    player:SetAttribute("IsAlive", false)
    
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        onCharacterAdded(character, player)
    end)
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)

while true do
    task.wait(1)
    local playerList = Players:GetPlayers()
    for i = 1, #playerList do
        local player = playerList[i]
        if player:GetAttribute("IsAlive") then
            local points = player.leaderstats.Points
            points.Value += 1
        end
    end
end


I tried adding a another function that basically onTouch it will cause 10 points to gain and then breaks. I have conceptual issues so it may have not accurately been carried out but there were no error/syntax's.

this
local pointPart1 = game.Workspace.PointsPlaceFolder.PointPart1

blacklist = {}
blacklist.findPlayer = function(player)
    for i,v in ipairs(blacklist) do
        if v==player then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

PointPart1.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
   if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild(“Humanoid”) then
    thePlayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent:FindFirstChild(“Humanoid”).Parent)
    if(thePlayer and not blacklist.findPlayer(thePlayer))
        thePlayer.leaderstats.Points.Value+=1
        table.insert(blacklist,thePlayer)
   end
end)


will add a point to the player whenever the part is touched, but then add the player to the blacklist, so that the player isnt allowed to touch it again, if you still want the player to still be able to get points from the part later,it would require a different solution
